# How to fix indentation for `dash.el` threading macros (e.g. `->>`)

Tags: indentation, dash.el

As I write more Elisp, I find myself using the threading macro increasingly often. However, since it is an imported, not a built-in one, the indentation is not like what I want it to be.

For example, I want the auto-indentation to be, not like this:

```el
(->> '(1 2 3 4)
  (mapcar #'1+)
  (seq-filter #'evenp)
  (reduce #'+))
```

but like this:

```el
(->> '(1 2 3 4)
     (mapcar #'1+)
     (seq-filter #'evenp)
     (reduce #'+))
```

...so that the inner expressions are aligned together vertically.

How can I specially designate the indent level, based on the expression's `car`?

Comment: AFAIK `->>` comes from `dash.el` and I just checked the current version of that, and it *does* indent your example the way you want.  So I guess you just need to update `dash`?

Comment: @phils That's odd, I just the version of my `dash` and it says `20210602.1928`, version `2.18.1`. It looks pretty recent, but it still does not provide such indentation. `(require 'dash)` did not help either.

Comment: I used `dash-2.18.1` from GNU ELPA.  The `->>` definition doesn't `declare` any indentation rules, so it works the way you want.  Do you see the same thing from `emacs -Q` if you load `dash`?

Comment: @phils The macro `->>` gained an indentation declaration after that release; try the more recent version on GNU-devel ELPA instead: https://elpa.gnu.org/devel/dash.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I do:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'dash
  (function-put '-> 'lisp-indent-function nil)
  (function-put '->> 'lisp-indent-function nil))
```

Dash maintainers refused to keep `->`/`->>` indentation in sync with other Lisps. See https://github.com/magnars/dash.el/pull/375#issuecomment-817947545

See [`(info "(elisp) Indenting Macros")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Indenting-Macros.html) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

The Dash project has gone back and forth on the indentation of these Clojure-inspired threading macros a couple of times in the past:

- https://github.com/magnars/dash.el/issues/108
- https://github.com/magnars/dash.el/pull/109
- https://github.com/magnars/dash.el/pull/188

And, most recently:

- https://github.com/magnars/dash.el/pull/375

This pull request (re)introduced the indentation that OP describes as undesirable for `->` and `->>` on 2021-03-08. However, this controversial change was never included as part of an official Dash release, and was present only for 4 months in the development version that can be installed from [GNU-devel ELPA](https://elpa.gnu.org/devel/dash.html) or [MELPA](https://melpa.org/#/dash).

The release of Dash [2.19.0](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el/releases/tag/2.19.0) on 2021-07-08 restored Clojure-like indentation for the macros `->`, `->>`, and `-->` for both development and non-development versions of the Dash package:

```el
(->> '(1 2 3 4)
     (mapcar #'1+)
     (seq-filter #'cl-evenp)
     (reduce #'+))
```

Once upgraded to this version, no further steps are required to achieve the desirable indentation, but see [Ivan's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/65153/15748) for a general mechanism to customise Elisp indentation.

Comment: Thanks for your effort on `dash.el`!